# SNMPv3 not in time window

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp

I try to query a Cisco SMB (small business switch) to read its hostname.

My code returns "not in time window (1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0).

Net-Snmp works fine. The difference I found using wireshark is that net-snmp sets msgAuthorativeEngineTime after it receives not in time window error.

```
Discovery discovery = Messenger.GetNextDiscovery(SnmpType.GetRequestPdu);
ReportMessage report = discovery.GetResponse(60000, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.105.9.10"), 161));

OctetString username = new OctetString("test");
var auth = new SHA1AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("Testtest123!"));
var priv = new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("Testtest123!"), auth);

// read switch hostname
GetRequestMessage request = new GetRequestMessage(VersionCode.V3, Messenger.NextMessageId, Messenger.NextRequestId, username, new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0")) }, priv, Messenger.MaxMessageSize, report);
ISnmpMessage reply = request.GetResponse(60000, router); (not in time window)
```

Please find a wireshark screenshot of sharp-snmp: [image: wireshark screenshot of sharp-snmp]

And net-snmp:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I fixed it reading [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpget/Program.cs source code.

I need to do two requests to sync time.

Comment: You should post the comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `snmpget` sample (updated link [here](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/Samples)), you have to call two times the `GetRequestMessage` method. Be aware that the code uses the `report` variable in the first call, then the `reply` one in the latter, otherwise it will not work (= not in time window message) (I lost half a day to get this!)